# Not displaying SESSION ITEM / VARIABLE codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi guys my session have data 
But i cant get an item to display for example i just want the ID

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1538534437 [logged_in] => 1 [profile] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 1 
[email] => teacher@email.com 
[role_id] => 2 
[tekteach_login_flag] => 1 
[date_registered] => 2018-07-27 16:07:50 
[deleted] => 0 
[first_name] => Elena 
[last_name] => Cruz 
[middle_name] => Santos 
[gender] => Female 
[birthday] => 1970-01-01 
[status] => Active 
[created_on] => 2018-06-01 05:28:26 
[created_by] => 
[modified_on] => 
[modified_by] => 0 
[deleted_by] => 0 ) )
```

My code is like this

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);

$userID = $this->session->userdata('id');

$this->session->set_userdata('id',$userID);

echo $this->session->userdata('id');
```

Comment: Have you auto loaded or initiated the session library? It will be better if you paste your whole controller code.

Comment: yes it is autoloaded, i am able to get the result now, btw thamk you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print_r shows that your id (and its friends) have been stored in an object called profile.

So I have created a little test script based on what you have shown and how you could read back those values.

```
//
// Using Objects - most likely from a Database result set
//
// Create the session test data
$profile = (object)array();
$profile->id = 1;
$profile->name = 'Fred';


// Display the full session
$this->session->set_userdata('profile', $profile);
var_dump($this->session->userdata());

$profile = $this->session->userdata('profile');
var_dump($profile);

echo 'userId is ' . $profile->id;  // Std Object
echo '<br>';
echo 'userId is ' . $this->session->profile->id; // Magic Method
```

Result

```
array (size=2)
  '__ci_last_regenerate' => int 1538540690
  'profile' => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'name' => string 'Fred' (length=4)

object(stdClass)[18]
  public 'id' => int 1
  public 'name' => string 'Fred' (length=4)

userId is 1
userId is 1
```

You can, of course, use print_r() instead of var_dump(). I just prefer var_dump().

Answer (score 0):

You are having profile object in session. Get id using below

```
$profile = $this->session->userdata('profile');
$id = $profile->id;
echo $id;
```